# Mobile virtual-keyboard pushes up content

Tags: html, css, css-position, virtual-keyboard

I have an html layout / css problem in a basic chat application.
There is a page with a chat-header a chat-body and a chat-footer.
Body contains the messages, it is scrollable, the footer contains the text input.
When the user clicks on the text input, the entire content is pushed up on mobile, and i can't see my header.

**Here is a snippet**

```css
body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100svh;
}

.chat {
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 15px;
}

.footer,
.header {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="header">
        <button>Menu</button>
    </div>
    <div class="chat">

        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum quod ex adipisci repellat doloremque consequuntur vero laboriosam odio blanditiis nobis illum esse assumenda dicta iste dolorem cumque, minima nam eos sapiente suscipit reiciendis, animi dolore! Ea nesciunt laboriosam explicabo hic. Temporibus cum vero voluptatum accusantium officia debitis recusandae ipsa praesentium perferendis inventore iusto voluptates pariatur consectetur sint repellat aperiam id sed velit, quis repellendus libero! Fugiat, ullam? Nihil minima repellat cumque laborum autem beatae ad corrupti excepturi veniam ut, animi facilis sapiente nemo harum consequuntur modi dicta eum velit laboriosam quaerat doloremque quod voluptatem earum iure. Consectetur corporis obcaecati commodi ea hic ex aut temporibus rerum illo eaque officiis, fugit ratione quod consequatur accusamus eligendi ad quas veniam ab nemo odio atque, beatae quibusdam tenetur! In accusantium perspiciatis accusamus tempore aliquid maiores eos tenetur ipsum doloremque facilis. Accusamus sunt, officiis deleniti omnis minus dolores blanditiis unde aliquam sequi ab dolorum, vero sed reiciendis repellat laborum hic quisquam. Provident deserunt eius voluptas cumque illo adipisci sed illum libero vero, sit, esse eos ullam ipsam fuga similique beatae corporis laudantium accusamus autem perspiciatis? Natus corrupti quas alias quibusdam iusto, molestias voluptatibus libero rem aut possimus omnis obcaecati repudiandae suscipit velit, maxime quis tempora. Harum eaque incidunt quasi dicta cupiditate beatae error voluptatum accusamus porro, veritatis aliquam. Repellendus veritatis ipsam rem velit atque doloremque placeat magnam accusamus nihil laborum? Rerum, quisquam deleniti minus sit quod dolores quo harum nam quos eligendi suscipit soluta alias asperiores aspernatur magni provident voluptas ad dolorum recusandae blanditiis eius esse. Consequuntur sunt voluptatem maiores necessitatibus officiis, ea veniam voluptas aspernatur facilis hic quae natus reprehenderit? Ratione nostrum, cupiditate voluptatibus magnam maxime repellendus, eos omnis aut quis ut molestiae quo labore animi porro quod earum? Officiis natus quaerat voluptatibus quisquam vero nisi consequuntur labore porro unde accusantium quia facere, sint placeat iusto itaque ullam magnam modi. Fuga quae magnam distinctio cupiditate! Nihil deleniti magni neque, adipisci ullam ipsum. Eius distinctio quidem dolor fugiat voluptates omnis expedita excepturi impedit maxime ut, deserunt laboriosam, ipsa porro sunt molestiae minima rerum voluptas accusantium tenetur amet, temporibus velit labore quia. Iusto, amet incidunt commodi voluptatem officiis dolor, modi expedita itaque optio libero quas dolorem? Ipsam necessitatibus quae non eius eveniet a expedita exercitationem ex natus, vero excepturi quam labore dolores! Saepe reprehenderit laudantium architecto quasi adipisci iusto consequatur error repellat velit, molestiae voluptatum excepturi culpa inventore necessitatibus facilis, eaque eum nostrum, harum consequuntur ipsa explicabo fugiat earum aliquam similique. Quos illo doloremque veniam! Commodi sed laudantium beatae assumenda sequi, error voluptate laboriosam ea, voluptatum voluptates quod impedit molestiae optio porro aperiam. Molestiae voluptatum voluptatem quia ut alias aspernatur praesentium ipsam animi quam laudantium enim aliquam ipsa minima blanditiis odio, aut nam minus eaque consectetur explicabo dolores eius expedita corporis placeat. Amet repellat vero, vitae laudantium expedita modi earum deleniti hic neque? Laudantium cumque, aliquam, praesentium, quos nulla nisi nihil facere velit consequatur ut ducimus nam? Quis nam odio delectus a consectetur vel esse explicabo quaerat ipsum fugiat quo neque sit harum reprehenderit aliquid, ab veniam recusandae voluptatibus reiciendis quos impedit et? Iste doloribus facilis deserunt perspiciatis nostrum enim cupiditate eum, impedit laborum corporis quas dolor consectetur labore at optio dicta molestiae placeat cum aut! Eligendi ipsum error corporis repudiandae quod ipsam. Quos illum ipsam assumenda dolorem fugiat unde totam pariatur similique sint, soluta quaerat minima ducimus, laborum natus ad quod iure ullam quis nam. Facere, provident nam. Aliquam quae sed, laudantium, non voluptas perferendis labore nihil dolor excepturi consequuntur similique eos quaerat accusantium aut corporis! Quia ipsam, recusandae aliquid blanditiis sit, at in ipsa vitae ducimus maiores excepturi vel provident ex omnis nulla deleniti facilis nostrum necessitatibus. Maxime reprehenderit velit adipisci amet in eum nostrum quod cumque eos! Aliquid architecto consequuntur obcaecati? Exercitationem et sit qui amet, dolores suscipit. Animi molestiae asperiores rerum, eaque aperiam consequatur eos ea voluptas neque inventore officia rem cumque non dolorem mollitia doloribus iure impedit distinctio sed reiciendis iusto ut reprehenderit id nihil. Quam nulla ex dignissimos debitis consequatur quasi fuga nesciunt quod, distinctio, quia ea voluptatem aliquam a temporibus reiciendis vitae aperiam pariatur officiis accusantium iure praesentium labore et maxime? Vitae impedit rem, eveniet at aspernatur accusamus voluptatum architecto, ipsam natus officiis quidem nobis nemo velit odit, illum minima provident excepturi! Laborum provident nisi dolorum placeat architecto adipisci quod quasi aliquid suscipit autem quas soluta, fuga repellat cumque. Tempora delectus totam modi vel dignissimos at dicta error, ea suscipit, ipsum magnam odio odit voluptates. Dolorum blanditiis natus quam, molestiae repudiandae, accusamus ea eveniet qui molestias ipsum error obcaecati beatae. Aut rerum nemo quos vero id pariatur debitis et molestiae consequuntur quam alias accusamus recusandae, sequi corrupti, maxime quaerat, autem magnam perferendis neque magni quibusdam placeat! Cum laudantium delectus sint assumenda natus illum unde hic nihil laboriosam rem dignissimos corporis quia, nostrum dolore! Iure totam nulla quaerat, rerum omnis porro modi magni assumenda inventore ipsa aut distinctio. Incidunt nostrum repellendus aperiam nihil ducimus ut similique vitae doloremque reprehenderit aliquid obcaecati laudantium, architecto impedit excepturi dolore molestias quod ullam quia, temporibus labore adipisci. Maiores quae mollitia accusamus quasi facilis eos, cum totam fugit vitae a eveniet enim accusantium soluta beatae ullam consectetur sit quos blanditiis ad eaque sapiente non. Beatae vel culpa doloremque non adipisci dicta quam voluptatibus, pariatur, autem unde modi minima maxime libero asperiores possimus! Iste in nesciunt voluptas reiciendis ullam ipsa rem sequi accusantium incidunt fugiat vitae esse consectetur dolor deserunt, quo mollitia nisi sapiente nam, neque eligendi eveniet vero? At quisquam magni suscipit eos accusamus eveniet, neque ratione labore fugit quam nam sunt exercitationem nobis! Ea nobis adipisci, alias dolorum enim eligendi quod voluptatem necessitatibus. Nulla rerum suscipit, quae non porro sequi accusantium consectetur expedita dolor eaque odio quia iste, in eius voluptates magnam atque quo. Asperiores consequatur dolor culpa totam quia unde omnis molestiae, voluptatibus temporibus? Molestiae omnis debitis nihil. Autem consequuntur doloribus unde ducimus tenetur quaerat aspernatur quidem delectus laudantium architecto cupiditate quae dignissimos in similique neque sint ipsum nobis illo, voluptatibus aliquid voluptates nulla tempore? Blanditiis ut nostrum deserunt tempore culpa cumque pariatur iste delectus quae fugit laboriosam at quisquam sit, ipsam nemo neque cum. Aspernatur id commodi possimus officia quos voluptatibus! Aperiam cum corporis ratione repellendus illo pariatur consequuntur, perferendis laboriosam debitis, cumque, explicabo nisi quasi earum sint. Vero deleniti ipsum accusamus quibusdam quo qui, reiciendis quia excepturi architecto consectetur, odit, maxime facere ab ad rerum libero aliquid quasi atque illo officiis sint? Necessitatibus cum quisquam qui quaerat illum temporibus laudantium, atque autem molestiae vel veniam quo sequi! Non ipsa velit possimus unde ratione debitis iure provident, animi, amet architecto beatae fuga ab itaque reiciendis vel vitae et facilis corporis molestiae soluta voluptatum hic eius id adipisci. Inventore a odio possimus enim dicta aliquam tempora quas ex tenetur soluta. Eum accusamus dicta exercitationem fuga dolores non reiciendis perferendis, sapiente deserunt alias a ad aperiam, quas nostrum qui necessitatibus at vel quam! Eum labore illo veniam reiciendis reprehenderit sed beatae odio debitis? Molestias ipsa assumenda harum praesentium iure magnam nesciunt nostrum. Vel libero cupiditate voluptas, culpa quia facere incidunt quaerat ab facilis. Sequi alias quod quas minus quae hic rem ipsa, impedit provident accusamus nesciunt dolorem sit ratione repudiandae, corporis dignissimos! Dignissimos eligendi, optio eos veritatis rerum nihil obcaecati corrupti doloribus deserunt quisquam accusamus, vitae ducimus maiores dolores ab aspernatur! Praesentium ipsam ex enim quidem iure repellat fuga laboriosam sint expedita. Aut minima tempora temporibus! Vero, at libero, ratione fuga inventore laboriosam ea harum nobis nostrum delectus explicabo assumenda facilis deleniti quidem magni non? Necessitatibus velit dolor, quis esse nobis ratione fugiat tempore delectus at cum, nulla, deserunt non animi labore voluptates veniam exercitationem voluptate nihil. Cupiditate a adipisci iste commodi voluptatem praesentium accusantium nostrum, explicabo doloremque? Consequuntur temporibus quos eligendi sunt harum praesentium soluta excepturi. Commodi quod ut nemo obcaecati mollitia quibusdam explicabo omnis! Dolorem, error aliquid esse sint enim autem numquam optio velit, eum commodi voluptas qui. Quasi, nisi id. Dolorum aliquid nobis maiores ab expedita ad nulla quae error! Modi fugiat voluptas eius tempore excepturi harum, ipsam architecto reprehenderit cumque ducimus, distinctio quisquam officiis nostrum ea, fuga ab temporibus voluptatem nisi vitae. Ducimus assumenda cum tempore eaque quas adipisci ut nostrum temporibus sunt natus aspernatur facere rerum inventore qui deserunt harum at accusamus, expedita magni nesciunt sequi enim dolore! Beatae, vitae pariatur dolor rerum est nihil suscipit explicabo delectus labore, sint minima? Fugit placeat quas quasi ullam error natus modi consequuntur nobis repellat quidem dicta doloribus dolorem suscipit tempora tenetur perspiciatis numquam quod ad, ducimus aliquam nihil dolores magnam unde. Porro modi velit ipsam quae beatae perferendis laborum, quos at consequatur nulla molestias debitis dolorum quod vitae optio? Perspiciatis at alias nesciunt ipsa dolores doloremque veniam! Dolores, praesentium enim, iusto aperiam dolor, incidunt molestiae similique quas consequatur modi eum quaerat! Vitae sapiente necessitatibus facere velit minus explicabo laborum amet. Illum eum ab fuga error dolor? Voluptates quisquam esse sint incidunt ex neque voluptas reiciendis laborum! Aperiam modi ipsa saepe a doloribus illo voluptatem optio explicabo eos, perferendis debitis. Nisi quis sequi error beatae cupiditate aliquam perspiciatis recusandae voluptatem modi.

    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type here..." name="" id="">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Here is how it looks like on mobile when the virtual keyboard is visible:**

[image]

The weird thing is that i can scroll the body or at least the document, even if i specified the following css for the body:

```
body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100svh;
}
```

I have tried without flex box, with different positions and different javascript alternatives.
Tried to make my header and footer fixed/absolute but it did not help either.

When my footer is fixed, it works in a way, but the header does not.

This javascript snippet is helping somewhat.

```
var body = document.querySelector("body");
if (window && window.visualViewport){
    visualViewport.addEventListener('resize', function(){
        let viewHeight = visualViewport.height;
        body.style.height = `${viewHeight}px`;
    });
}
```

It does resize my body to the correct height when the virtual keyboard is visible but i can still scroll the entire document??

The javascript "fix" is what i want, but without the ability to scroll the document meanwhile. I want the same chat behaviour which is on discord or any other message platform.

When the virtual keyboard pops up, i want to squeeze my chat message body into the available space along with my header and footer.

**Here is a gif demonstrating the javascript fix problem:**

[image]

Comment: I can't belive there is no answer to this simple problem. :(